# Pandas two dataframes multiplication?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames (A and B)

```
A:
column 1, column 2, column 3
0.1        0.5       0.7


B:
row 1          5
row 2          6
row 3          7
```

how do I perform multiplication to get like

```
(0.1)*5,  (0.5)* 6,  and (0.7)*7?
```

In other words, how do I multiply the value in the first row of B with the value in the first column of A, the second row of B with the value in the second column of B, and etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want to multiply their values without respect to whether they are rows or columns.

```
pd.Series(A.values.ravel() * B.values.ravel())

0    0.5
1    3.0
2    4.9
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: So in fact, if the dataframe of A has more columns (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) and B has fewer columns (col3, col4, col5), can I replace the values of col3, col4, col5 in A with the values of col3, col4, col5 in B? How could I do it?

Comment: @JunJang that is a new question. The community would benefit more from yo posting it as a separate question. Also, it is best for you, the community, and the people trying to answer your question, that you try to be specific about your problem.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [161]: B
Out[161]:
   col3  col4  col5
0     5     6     7

In [162]: A
Out[162]:
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0   0.1   0.2   0.3   0.4   0.5

In [163]: A[B.columns]
Out[163]:
   col3  col4  col5
0   0.3   0.4   0.5

In [164]: A[B.columns].mul(B.values.ravel())
Out[164]:
   col3  col4  col5
0   1.5   2.4   3.5
```

**UPDATE2:**

```
In [169]: A.loc[:, B.columns] = A[B.columns].mul(B.values.ravel())

In [170]: A
Out[170]:
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0   0.1   0.2   1.5   2.4   3.5
```

**OLD answer:**

Not that nice compared to @piRSquared's solution, but it should work:

```
In [116]: A.T.mul(B.values).T
Out[116]:
   column 1  column 2  column 3
0       0.5       3.0       4.9
```

or better:

```
In [123]: A.mul(B.values.ravel())
Out[123]:
   column 1  column 2  column 3
0       0.5       3.0       4.9
```

Comment: Looks nice to me!

Comment: Super nice now!

Comment: @piRSquared, yes, now it looks better :)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: So in fact, if the dataframe of A has more columns (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) and B has fewer columns (col3, col4, col5), can I replace the values of col3, col4, col5 in A with the values of col3, col4, col5 in B? How could I do it?

Comment: @JunJang, could you provide __reproducible__ data sets?

Comment: Say you have dataframe A:
col1  col2   col 3  col4   col5
0.1   0.2    0.3      0.4    0.5

You also have dataframe B:
col3   col4    col5
5      6          7

how do you overlap the col3, col4, and col5 of A such that you have:
col1  col2  col3   col4   col5
0.1    0.2    5       6           7

Comment: @JunJang, please check update - is that what you want?

Comment: thank you very much.. but I still want to maintain col1 and col2 in the end result. the end result should be:
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
0.1   0.2     5      6        7

Comment: @JunJang, UPDATE2 - ?

Comment: @JunJang I left a similar msg on my answer, but you're veering away from your original question. Consider whether or not that question has been answered and choose the answer that helped you the most. MaxU has done a lot here to help you out. I'd advise you to accept this one and ask a new question where you can be clear about what you want. Trust me, we like questions. We just want them to be precise :-)

Comment: @piRSquared, yes, you're right. Changed questions might invalidate already given answers...